# Capturing sound input with low latency in the browser

Tags: javascript, audio, unity-game-engine, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to capture low-latency sound input in the browser? mainly for recording a guitar. (I know it depends on the hardware too, but let's assume the hardware is good enough).
I tried to use the Web Audio API, but it had somewhat bad latency. Are there any other technologies out there that gives high performance sound-input capturing in the browser? Is it possible to use Unity3D for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing any processing? I've found latency to be well within the acceptable range for recording guitar, even with live effects.

Maybe try reducing the `bufferSize` on any `ScriptProcssor`s you might be using.

Comment: With chrome?
Any chance to post some example that worked fine for you?

Comment: This works just fine for me in Chrome: https://gist.github.com/kevincennis/6043052

Comment: Which hardware and OS are you using, @KevinEnnis? I'm experiencing latency with basic setup even if I don't have live effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Web Audio API latency was bad" ignores a lot of potential issues.  Low latency nearly always needs some tweaking.

1) Latency is considerably lower (3ms or so, commonly) on OSX than on Windows (10ms or so common).  It can be VERY high on Linux, mostly due to hardware tuning issues.

2) Latency can be tuned on most systems, but you are ALWAYS going to have latency in digital audio.

3) On OSX, at least, you can also reduce the latency by increasing the sample rate - it's ~3ms at 44.1kHz, but if you record at 88.2kHz it's half that.  :)

I play and record guitar through web audio on my Mac, and find it completely acceptable.  YMMV.

Oh, and ScriptProcessorNodes are very bad for keeping your latency low - it is far and away best if you can eliminate them from your audio path.

Comment: I've also found Linux has high latency. Using that minimal example https://gist.github.com/kevincennis/6043052 I still had far too much latency to comfortably play guitar. However, I get low latency when bypassing the browser, connecting the source and sink on alsa level. Wouldn't that make it an implementation issue rather than hw/driver issue?

Comment: I have 200ms latency on Windows 10 Both Chrome and Firefox with simple example (https://jsfiddle.net/zlelik/xfq3ykp7/49/) without any processing.
How to make it 20-50 ms? Is there any guidance, how to tune it and reach 20ms? 20 ms I think is perfect for me. I need it for guitar as well :)