# What technologies are suitable for low latency input (mic) audio crunching in the browser?

Tags: audio, html5-audio

Which technologies are suitable for listening to microphone input (playing of music instrument), crunching the data (within browser, nothing goes back to server), and showing the results live to user?

Latency is a key here. I found many audio libraries, however, all processing would be confined to user's browser which is my idea.

PS: I found similar question, but not the same: [Capturing sound input with low latency in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746622/capturing-sound-input-with-low-latency-in-the-browser)

Comment: I have use Web Audio API for this ... its a javascript API yet interacts with audio using very efficient binary float buffers ... for showing results canvas will work however for maximum speed use webgl to render live charting

Comment: @ScottStensland What latency could you achieve with this approach?